# Block Virtual keyboard popup for a particular TextField/TextArea in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

How to block virtual keyboard pop up for a TextField/TextArea? I tried using  `inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNone` and also declared an `InputMethod` by setting `Visible:false` but nothing is working.

If i click on TextEdit/TextArea keyboard pops-up. Is there any way to block the Virtual Keyboard Popup?

Comment: Which platform and why you want to do that?

Comment: @Macias I am using QT 5.9 on Windows and I am having my own keyboard with some  button layout and customized keys . So I want to disable default virtual keyboard for some Text fields .

Comment: I dealt with this by setting the ReadOnly property to true.